# Yii 1.1.x XSS Injection in URL

Tags: php, yii, xss

I findout my app is not safe to xss from URL, when I navigate to url:

```
http://host.local/app/Dashboard<script>alert("test")</script>
```

The script will inject into error message:

```
The system is unable to find the requested action "adminDashboard
```

How to stop this?

Comment: 1) Report to the maintainers that their default error pages are prone to SQL injection. 2) Define your own error pages?!

Comment: actually it is xss injection and I'm using a fork version. it is really easy to stop attack. the main branch of yii is protected to xss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was really easy:
just check your error handler in config file 
and add CHtml::encode($error["message"]) in the view.